# How can I get image associated with html input button to change when clicked

Tags: javascript, html

I want the open.png image associated with the image button to become close.png when I click on the input image button and go back to open.png when i click on it again.

Im stuck on how I do this, but I do have a jsfiddle example ready to go https://jsfiddle.net/ijabz/xgLz76kn/40/

```
<table>
<tr>
    <td><input type="image" onclick="return toggleMe('1')" src="http://jthink.net/songkong/scratch/open.png"/></td>
    <td>Column 2</td>
</tr>
<tr id="1" style="display:none">
    <td colspan="2">
        <table>
            <tr>
                <td>Inner Data 1</td>
                <td>Inner Data 2</td>
            </tr>    
        </table>                 
    </td>   
</tr>    
<tr>
    <td><input type="image" onclick="return toggleMe('2')" src="http://jthink.net/songkong/scratch/open.png"/></td>
    <td>Column 2</td>
</tr>
<tr id="2" style="display:none">
    <td colspan="2">
        <table>
            <tr>
                <td>Inner Data 3</td>
                <td>Inner Data 4</td>
            </tr>    
        </table>                 
    </td>   
</tr>        
</table>
```

Javascript function is

```
function toggleMe(a){
var e=document.getElementById(a);
if(!e)return true;
if(e.style.display=="none"){
e.style.display="table-row"
}
else{
e.style.display="none"
}
return true;
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**EDIT:** The accepted answer works but is fare more complex than it needs to, ref. updated sample on fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/xgLz76kn/53/

```
<table>
<tr>
    <td><input type="image" onclick="toggleMe(this)" value="Tracks" src="http://jthink.net/songkong/scratch/open.png"/></td>
    <td>Column 2</td>
</tr>
<tr id="1">
    <td colspan="2">
        <table>
            <tr>
                <td>Inner Data 1</td>
                <td>Inner Data 2</td>
            </tr>    
        </table>                 
    </td>   
</tr>    
</table> 
<script type='text/javascript'>
function toggleMe(btn){
    btn.src = btn.src=="http://jthink.net/songkong/scratch/open.png" ? "http://jthink.net/songkong/scratch/close.png" : "http://jthink.net/songkong/scratch/open.png";
}
</script>
```

**EDIT ends**

Having http://jthink.net/songkong/scratch/open.png on both rows will give the same image

Your sample on fiddle has no images and the texts in id='2' is the same as in id='1'

If you check a modified version on https://jsfiddle.net/xgLz76kn/48/ you will see that it works as expected

```
<table>
<tr>
    <td><input type="button" onclick="toggleMe(1)" value="Tracks"/></td>
    <td>Column 2</td>
</tr>
<tr id="1" style="display:none">
    <td colspan="2">
        <table>
            <tr>
                <td>Inner Data 1</td>
                <td>Inner Data 2</td>
            </tr>    
        </table>                 
    </td>   
</tr>    
<tr>
    <td><input type="button" onclick="toggleMe(2)" value="Tracks"/></td>
    <td>Column 2</td>
</tr>
<tr id="2" style="display:none">
    <td colspan="2">
        <table>
            <tr>
                <td>Inner Data 3</td>
                <td>Inner Data 4</td>
            </tr>    
        </table>                 
    </td>   
</tr>        
</table> 

function toggleMe(a){
    var el = document.getElementById(a);
    el.style.display = el.style.display=="none" ? "table-row" : "none";
}
```

Comment: thanks I prefer your answer because you still use input type button which semantically makes more sense. I did have one issue when applied to my actual code though in the html src is set to "../../images/open.png) but when I check the value in the javascript it has become the full path "http://localhost:8080/images/open.png" - how do I address this discrepancy in a portable way (as http://localhost:8080/images/open.png will not be the path of the application when deployed to production)

Answer (score 1):

[JSFIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/mus44sum/1/)

change

`input type="image"`

to

`<img onclick="return toggleMe('2')" src="http://jthink.net/songkong/scratch/open.png"/>`

and add an event listener for the click function on your img

```
$(document).ready(function(){
$('img').on({
    'click': function() {
         var src = ($(this).attr('src') === 'http://jthink.net/songkong/scratch/open.png')
            ? 'http://jthink.net/songkong/scratch/close.png'
            : 'http://jthink.net/songkong/scratch/open.png';
         $(this).attr('src', src);
    }
});
```

});

Comment: Now remember to include jQuery in your project!

Comment: okay thanks that worked (although does seem weird you can't do with buttons) but looking at your code that function will be written for every img element in the html - how do I restrict to just for the particular images I want it to occur for.

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/mus44sum/2/ I updated it, give the images you want a class. @PaulTaylor